# jQuery Class change not updating until mouse over

Tags: jquery, class, hover, addclass

I have a menu and each menu item is a span with a class set in css:

`.newClass {color: red}`

`.oldClass {color:black} oldClass:hover {color:blue;}`

When you click on a menu item the class is changed with:
`$(this).removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass');`
which works fine.

When another menuItem is click I change the classes back on the current menu item with:
`$(this).removeClass('newClass').addClass('oldClass');`

The problem is when the class is changed back, the change is not reflected until I mouse over the menu Item.  So the menu item color stays red until I mouse it and then it changes back to black with a blue hover.

See Gaby's example in the comments for what should be happening

Here is my actual code:

`$('.headingRev').removeClass('headingRev').addClass('heading');

$(this).removeClass('heading').addClass('headingRev');`

and here is the css:

`.heading {color: #bb1f1a;}

.heading:hover {color: #e9b49e;text-decoration:none;}

.headingRev {color: #e9b49e;}`

Comment: can you also add the code you use to detect clicks? has caused me issues in the past. how do you detect clicks on other items?

Comment: please show how you assign the events of hover (*if you do*) and click .. btw, you are missing a `.` before the `oldClass:hover`

Comment: A small, self-contained example of code that reproduces the problem would be **very** helpful. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a nice way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

A possible problem could be the way you remove the selection from the current menu item..

you should not use `this` if you are doing it from inside the click, because `this` would point to the clicked element, and not the previously current one.. if that is the case then you should use `$('.newClass').removeClass('newClass').addClass('oldClass');`

see some code that works at http://www.jsfiddle.net/khGRW/

**Update**

I see now.. you are using Cufon, which replaces the text with images or canvas elements..

This make it unresponsive to normal DOM changes.

You need to call the `Cufon.refresh('#content')` after changing the class to an element (*that is not currently under `hover` event*) to force it to repaint the menu according to the current state of the DOM.

The `hover` effect is taken care automatically because they support that option, but that is where the DOM monitoring ends from the Cufon side..

Comment: Sorry, yes I already doing that.  The correct element is being targeted, but is just not being updated immediately. Your sample code is primarily the same as mine, yet yours works and mine does not.

Comment: @Clark .. hmm weird ..  make sure your classes are correctly capitalized in all places .. because they are case sensitive.. Also if you can post a working copy of your code, we can better see where it fails .

Comment: I have copied and pasted my exact code into my original question and I can't see why it doesn't work.  Because the class change is actually taking effect, but why do I have to mouse over the menu item to see the change.  Here is the actual site so you can see the menu behaviour I am talking about: http://urban-provocations.com/

Comment: @Clark, the problem is with Cufon. I have updated my answer with the solution for this problem..

Comment: Spot on Gaby, thanks a bunch.  You can imagine how frustrating that was.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach:

```
<ul>
<li class="ordinary">Menu 1</li>
<li class="ordinary">Menu 2</li>
<li class="ordinary">Menu 3</li>
</ul>

$('ul li').click(function(){
  $('ul li').removeClass("highlight").addClass("ordinary");
  $(this).removeClass("ordinary").addClass("highlight");
});
```

1. when click on a menu item, make all menu items to ordinary class
2. make the clicked menu to the highlight class